# php need textarea how to make a hard limit per line for run over

Tags: php, css

I have 2 differnt areas that is used  for a chat  one on user page one for global  comments. Everything works fine for the most part  all tho i  end up with a run over. It will not do a hard stop and start a new line. so its a run over  for what i am looking to achieve.  I would like it to  be just in the code and not use css file  so the code  is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo 
        '<div id="Comment'.$row['id'].'">
             <table width="290">
               <tr>
                 <td width="60" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img src="'.$row['image'].
                   '"   width="60"height="60" /></td>
                 <td width="220">
                   <span class="CommentName"
                     onClick="Stats('.$row['user_id'].')">'.$row['username'].'</span>
                   <span class="Time">'.time_elapsed_string($row['timestamp']).'</span>
                 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td class="Comment" valign="top">'.$row['comment'].'</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
         <br />';
}
```

This should have a hard stop 40  and  start a new line 
the next  bit of code in use is

```
<textarea 
    id="social" maxlength="300" style="width: 600; max-width: 600; 
    height: 80; max-height: 100;"></textarea>
<br />
```

any help  would   be great  do not want  to use css to fix   but will as if its the only way

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is really the only way to limit a text area entry like that. With a `<input type="text"/>` you can add `maxlength="x"` and the browser will enforce it.

If all you want to do is break it up on your end, I would grab the 40th character, find the next space and then insert a line break using PHP.

Comment: i do use some  JavaScript  with in the area  basally this is a browser game and would like  the hard limit  so ASCII  messages can be made  to work with out the run over. So player insert the ASCII  and  i think most would be 40 px   by 5 rows or somethin alone them lines